# Dot Matrix Shrunk after print using the latest chrome 60.0.3112.78

Tags: javascript, html, web, pdf.js, dot-matrix

I've been using chrome as my main browser for my web application, lately i decided to update my chrome but suddenly my printout got an issue.

Upon using a Dot Matrix the text got shrunk, why is that? I already explore its settings.

Btw, im using PDFJS, as my viewer.

-Ricky

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it has something to do with the dpi settings when I was using windows. I simply chose the 120x144 dpi in Quality Options. Try looking at the printer preferences and the chrome print dialog settings. I both adjusted them into the same 120x144 dpi.